# Bar Chart Axis Labels

Tags: labels, charts

Working with a client that uses D3 graphing. They are running into an issue when using a bar chart the label for the data entry is becoming extremely long (30+ characters) and rotating the text to 45degrees to make it fit.

Other than the obvious answer of char limit the labels has anyone found a good fix for this?

Answer (score 2):

**Consider using an effect similar to [CSS overflow:ellipsis](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-overflow/)**

Choose a maximum number of chars that work, and when labels are longer, truncate using the ellipsis.

If/when the user attempts to interact with the label to read more, show the full label in a tooltip (or similar) on hover.

Answer (score 0):

**a.** Truncating the words if it surpasses a certain length

**b.** Using multiple lines in the label

**c.** Rotating the labels 90 degrees. This has the disadvantage of being harder to read, unless you...

**d.** ... swap the axis if possible. The vertical axis might be able to better accomodate longer labels and multi-line labels.